# Div alignment, Avoid same html in two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix this jsfiddle.

The problem is that I want the first two divs(with class="fbox") to be in one line and at same level. I can drag the image to the container div. It duplicates the html, as I want but i also want to limit the use of image. for example if I have used the first image in horizontal div then I don't want that image to be in vertical div at the same time. I want to remove it from the other div. To better elaborate, I have created a jsfiddle. I am new so please excuse me if I haven't explained everything properly. Take a look and please let me know where I am going wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/KWut6/373/

Thanks

```js
$('#x').bind('dragstart', function(e) {
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', '#x');
});
$('#y').bind('dragstart', function(e) {
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', '#y');
});

$('#drop-box').bind('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).html($(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text')).clone());
  return false;
}).bind('dragover', false);

$('#drop-box2').bind('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).html($(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text')).clone());
  return false;
}).bind('dragover', false);
```

```css
#plot {
  width: 512px;
  min-height: 512px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/large-glossy-icons/512/Chart_xy.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.fbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<image src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/" draggable="true" id="x">
  <image src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/steamplane/images/b/b0/Happy_Face_100x100.gif/revision/latest?cb=20120104232844" draggable="true" id="y">
    </br>

    <div id="drop-box" class="fbox" style="border: 1px solid;  min-height:512px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div id="plot" class="fbox">hallo</div>

    <div style="padding-left:104px;">
      <div id="drop-box2" class="fboxf" style="border: 1px solid;  min-height:100px; width: 512px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the divs were:
For such a layout you must set the float propert to left for each div

Comment: And for checking the divs for the data and removing the data from the first div if the data in both divs is same. Following code did the trick:  ` if($('#div1').html()==$('#div2').html()){ 
  $('#div1').empty(); `